# When we pressed upload image button, the following error shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, expo

Please check error, the error show: Key "cancelled" in the image picker result is deprecated. By the way I used canceled

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Alert, Button, Image, View, StyleSheet,Platform } from 'react-native'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'
import Constants from 'expo-constants'


const Fine_Repair_Request = () => {
 const [image,setimage] = useState(null);

 useEffect( async() => {
  if(Platform.OS !== 'web'){
    const {status} =await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if(status !== 'granted'){
      alert('Permission denied')
    }
  }
 },[])
   
   const PickImage = async()=>{
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing:true,
      aspect:[4,3],
      quality:1
    })
    console.log(result)
    if(!result.canceled){
      setimage(result.uri)
    }
   }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Upload Image" onPress={PickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{uri:image}}/>}
    </View>
  )
}
export default Fine_Repair_Request;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})
```

```
 Error:  WARN  Key "cancelled" in the image picker result is deprecated and will be removed in SDK 48, use "canceled" instead
 WARN  Key "uri" in the image picker result is deprecated and will be removed in SDK 48, you can access selected assets through the "assets" array instead
```

Answer (score 5):

removing the console.log got rid of the error message for me .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

So, your problem is that you are accessing a deprecated propertie and you aren't accessing ok to the uri of the image.

From the `expo-image-picker` this is what a result response looks like:

```js
// When you run this example and pick an image, you will see the image that you picked show up in your app, and a similar log will be shown in the console:

{
  "assets": [
    {
      "assetId": "C166F9F5-B5FE-4501-9531",
      "base64": null,
      "duration": null,
      "exif": null,
      "fileName": "IMG.HEIC",
      "fileSize": 6018901,
      "height": 3025,
      "type": "image",
      "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/cropped1814158652.jpg"
      "width": 3024
    }
  ],
  "canceled": false,
  "cancelled": false
}
```

In order to be able to get the uri of the selected asset you have to access the `assets` array and then the image:

```js
console.log(result.assets[0].uri) // Will print the uri of the first selected image
```

The propertie `cancelled` is deprecated also, so just use the key that they are suggesting to you `canceled`

- [Expo Image Picker Result Response](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#usage)
- [Expo Image Picker Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/)

Comment: Why are you downvoting me? Its the correct answer, just read the docs lmao

Answer (score 0):

use

```
result?.assets[0]?.uri
```

instead of

```
result?.uri
```

Answer (score -1):

for Error: WARN Key "cancelled" try removing the console.log and add delete result.cancelled;

```
const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
    // Explore the result
    //console.log(result);
    if (!result.canceled) {
      ///// add this line
      delete result.cancelled;

      .......

    }
  }
```

and for WARN Key "uri"

```
setImage(result.assets[0].uri)

//instead of

setImage(result.uri)
```

then the full code :

```
   const PickImage = async()=>{
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing:true,
      aspect:[4,3],
      quality:1
    })
    // console.log(result) to delete
    if(!result.canceled){
      delete result.cancelled;
      setimage(result.assets[0].uri)
    }
   }
```